# React Render not updating on response from Ajax query

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my component that populates an array that determines what will be displayed in the `render` function (obviously the `componentDidMount` function)

But nothing happens when it updates the `this.state.containers`.. I've put a `console.log` into the first `render` loop, which successfully displays:

[image: Image of JSON Response]

But then nothing changes on the client side so I don't know if my loops are bad but I get no JS errors. So I'm not sure what the problem is, pretty new to React so any help would be great thanks.

```
var AdminForumContainer = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { containers: [] }
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/admin/manage/forum/populate',
            success: function(data) {
                var {containers} = this.state;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    containers.push(data[i]);
                }
                this.setState({containers});
            }.bind(this)
        })  
    },
    createMainThread: function(containerid) {

    },
    createSubThread: function(containerid) {

    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.containers.map(function(container) {
                    {console.log(container)}
                    <table key={container.containerid} className="containers">
                        <caption>{container.containername}</caption>
                        <thead className="containerTitle">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">Main Threads</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Thread Name</td>
                                <td>Delete</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                                container.mainthreads.map(function(mainthread) {
                                    return (
                                    <tr key={mainthread.threadid}>
                                        <td>{mainthread.threadname}</td>
                                        <td><button className="button alert">Delete</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text"/></td>
                                <td><button className="button">Create</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">Sub Threads</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                                container.mainthreads.map(function(subthread) {
                                    return (<tr key={subthread.threadid}>
                                        <td>{subthread.threadname}</td>
                                        <td><button className="button alert">Delete</button></td>
                                    </tr>)
                                })
                            }
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text"/></td>
                                <td><button className="button">Create</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<AdminForumContainer/>, document.getElementById("AdminForumContainer"))
```

Comment: Can we see the initial state of your app?

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like that:

```
            var containers = this.state.containers;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                containers.push(data[i]);
            }
            this.setState({containers: containers});
```

Does it work now ? What does show    this.setState({containers: containers}, function() { console.log(this.state)); ?

Answer (score 0):

You're actually *mutating* your state, which is best avoided. That is, your for-loop is directly updating `this.state.containers`, whereas state properties should be treated as read only, and only `setState()` should update them.

So what's happening is you've already updated `this.state.containers` by the time you call `this.setState()`. I'm no expert on React internals, but what I *think* is happening is `setState()` does a check to see if the state object property differs from the one you pass in; and here's the thing: it doesn't. The `containers` array you passed in is the same as `this.state.containers`. Therefore your component doesn't re-render.

My suggestion is to avoid mutating `this.state.containers`. You can use `Array#concat` to append the new data. Note that `Array#concat` doesn't mutate the array, it creates a new one.

```
 success: function(data) {
     // add a loop here if you need to manipulate the data response in some way
     this.setState({
         containers: this.state.containers.concat(data)
     });
 }.bind(this)
```

**UPDATE - 10 Dec 2015**

A correction is in order.

Whilst I still think the above is good advice, I no longer believe it to be the source of your problem. Experimenting with React has shown my above conjecture about the nature of `setState` to be false. React does not compare the old state to the new state before re-rendering (unless `componentWillUpdate` is overridden specifically to do this). You can call `this.setState()` with all or a subset of the existing state, an empty object or no argument at all, and it will still force a re-render. What it compares is not the old state to the new state, but the old rendered output to the new rendered output.